# how to recover power lost due to correcting for multiple comparisons?

Tags: statistical-power, bonferroni, false-discovery-rate, familywise-error

The right hand side plot descrives 7 treatments over the same 6 animals.

- The groups are paired.
- Measurements are log2 transformed (important for the design of the study)
- The assumtions for repeated measures ANOVA are not met. So I applied the Friedman test and it showed significant effects.
- With Bonferroni (FWER) none of the contrasts are significant. And with Benjamini-Hochberg (FDR, more sensitive) I also do not get significancy.

There is a major biological effect but is lost due to the multiple comparisons correction. What would you suggest to improve the power of my analysis?

A comparisson between two different methods to measure the same parameter are shown. Method 1 produced significant differences, but not method 2.

[image]

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, corrections are performed to reduce the chance of a type 1 error. How do you know that the effect that was significant before the correction but which was not significant afterwards was not a type 1 error?

Comment: ok, so a bit of context: these measurments (levels of a molecule) were taken with a very precise method. Before, the same parameter was measured by a less precise method and showed the same pattern of expression for the 4 last groups and the differences were significant (the first three groups were not included due to monetary constrains). Also, this is log2 transformed biological data. So a difference of 2logs indicates actually 4 folds of difference and that can have a large impact in biological processes.

Comment: If you _know_ that the difference between the measurements are different, then why do you need to use with inferential statistics?

Comment: Any Journal will require p-values for publishing these results

Comment: As far as I can see, what you have here is a failure to replicate. That could be because the second result is a type 2 error (which is what you seem to think it is), or it could be because the first result was a type 1 error. Now, it could be that you've done something inappropriate in your analysis which has given you erroneous results, but it may just be that the results vary in your different samples/studies. Trying to find ways to twist your results to say what you believe they ought to is [p-hacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dredging) and bad science.

Comment: I do not think there is a failure to replicate the results. Both methods show very similar differences between the same groups. The method 1 show this molecule as significantly different between groups. My goal is not to hack p values but to make sense of the results of method 2, where more groups are included.